# How to use a scoring metric other than rsquared for an SVR?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I've searched through the previous questions and I can't quite find what I'm looking for. Perhaps I'm phrasing the question incorrectly, so if that's the case I do apologize in advance.

I'm trying to essentially do my own grid search over an entire data set without using `GridsearchCV`, since `GridSearchCV` requires a cross-validation split.

I'm using `ParameterGrid` to do this:

```
# optimization area - set params
parameters = [
    {'kernel': ['rbf'],
     'gamma': [1e-4, 1e-3, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9],
     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]}]

# loop through each of the parameters and find the best set
for g in ParameterGrid(parameters):
    regressor.set_params(**g)
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

If my understanding is correct, I'd now need to compute a score on `X_train` and `y_train` for each of the parameter combinations and track the best one to apply those parameters to the test set.

When the following line of code is the one below, I get no error in the code and it returns an r^2 value:

```
score = regressor.score(X_train, y_train)
```

However, when I try to compute something different than the r^2 value, such as mean absolute error for example, as in this line of code, I get the following error:

```
score = metrics.mean_absolute_error(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

> ({0}!={1})".format(y_true.shape[1], y_pred.shape[1])) ValueError:
>   y_true and y_pred have different number of output (8!=1)

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`metrics.mean_absolute_error` is supposed to take output of your model, not its input, here you should call

`metrics.mean_absolute_error(regressor.predict(X_train), y_train)`

BTW

> I'm trying to essentially do my own grid search over an entire data
>   set without using GridsearchCV, since GridSearchCV requires a
>   cross-validation split.

You shouldn't do that, since there is no guarantee that optimal parameters obtained that way will generalize.

Comment: ahh - silly mistake. Thank you!